# Solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}=-3y-2y^\prime.$ Describe the motion of the system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}=-3y-2y^\prime.$ With initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y^\prime(0)=0$ Will the motion be periodic? What is the limit behaviour of $y$ as $x\to+\infty$? Will the system oscillate around equilibrium?

So first I solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}+2y^\prime+3y=0$ using the characteristic polynomial:

$r^2+2r+3=0$

The solutions are $r=-1\pm i\sqrt{2}$

Thus a general solution is $y(x)=c_1e^{(-1+i\sqrt{2})x}+c_2e^{(-1-i\sqrt{2})x}$

Using Eulers formula, $y(x)=ae^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x)+be^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$

Using the initial conditions $y(0)=1=a(1)(1+0)=a$ thus $a=1$

And using $y^\prime(x)=-e^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x)-\sqrt{2}e^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}be^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x)-be^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$

We get $y^\prime(0)=0=-1+0+\sqrt{2}b-0$ thus $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

So $y_p(x)=e^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$ is the particular solution

I can see $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}y(x)=0$ since $\frac{1}{e^x}\to0$

So this won't be periodic. But how do I determine that the system will oscillate around the equilibrium? Is it simply because I have a form of $\cos(x)+\sin(x)$?

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add the initial conditions i will edit.

Comment: You forgot to apply the chain rule. For example $(\sin{(\sqrt{2}x)})'=\sqrt{2}\cos{(\sqrt{2}x)}$

Comment: Observe that the answer has infinitely many roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given initial conditions you should get that
$$y(x)=e^{-x}\left(\cos{(\sqrt{2}x)}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}2\sin{(\sqrt{2}x)}\right)$$
which, applying double-angle formulae, simplifies to
$$y(x)=\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}e^{-x}\sin{(\sqrt{2}x+\arctan{(\sqrt{2})})}$$
Now $e^{-x}\gt0$ but $\sin{(\sqrt{2}x+\arctan{(\sqrt{2})})}$ regularly oscillates between $\pm1$ hence the overall behaviour of $y(x)$ is oscillatory about the equilibrium point.

Comment: You are missing an $x$ as the argument in the sine terms.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that may confuse you is the $ e^{-x} $ but you have to understand that this is the amplitude of the system and it is not constant. It changes via an exponential law and as you stated as $x\rightarrow \infty$ the amplitude goes to zero and this implies that the system is stable. The motion will be periodic as there are the sine and cosine terms and the oscillations will have a constant angular frequency of $ \omega = \sqrt{2} $ but this won't be oscillations with a constant amplitude as you have encountered, they will decay with the exponential $ e^{-x} $ and they will be bounded within the exponential envelope (dotted line) as seen in the picture below.
[image]

As a matter of fact, you could have other functions that describe the amplitude which changes and the oscillations will always be bounded by the shape of the amplitude function. Few examples:
$$ y(t) = t\sin(t) $$
The oscillations should be bounded by the function $f(x) = x$
[image]
New example:
$$ y(t) = \sin(0.07t)\cdot\sin(t) $$
[image]
The oscillations should be bounded by the function $f(x) = \sin(0.7x)$.You bound a sine function with an other sine function of different frequency! I highlighted the envelopes. In the end oscillations of form:
$$y(t) = f(t)\sin(\omega t + \phi)$$
are bounded by the shape of the function $f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your general solution of $y(x)=ae^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x) +be^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)$ is correct. You also determined that $a=1$ given the initial condition $y(0)=1,$ which is correct. However, you determined $y'(x)$ incorrectly. You should have gotten, using the product rule and chain rule, that $y'(x)=-e^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x)-\sqrt{2}e^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)-be^{-x}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)+\sqrt{2}be^{-x}\cos(\sqrt{2}x).$

Substituting $y'(0)=0$ gives $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and so $y(x)=e^{-x}\left(\cos(\sqrt{2}x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)\right)$. This equation can be rewritten as $e^{-x}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\cos(\sqrt{2}x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sin(\sqrt{2}x)\right)\right).$ Notice that $\sqrt\frac{2}{3}=\sin(\arctan(\sqrt{2}))$ and $\sqrt\frac{1}{3}=\cos(\arctan(\sqrt{2})).$ Now we can use the addition identity for $\sin x$ to get that the expression is equivalent to $y(x)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}e^{-x}\left(\sin(\sqrt{2}x+\arctan(\sqrt{2}))\right).$ Since $e^{-x}>0\;\forall x$ and $\sin(\sqrt{2}x+\arctan(\sqrt{2}))$ oscillates between $\pm 1$ with period $\sqrt{2}\pi,$ the system oscillates around equilibrium.

Finally, as $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}=0,$ the limit at $\infty$ is 0.